# Report Parameters Location in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

![enter image description here][1]I have a few of reports in SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 which presents ask the user for parameters such as begin/end dates, or lastname to search in a database, etc.
I just follow the basics when designing the reports, and after and build and deployed, I give the URL to my user.
Now, the user has complained that at the point where the report is asking for the parameters, the user doesn't see the name of the report, so since there a few of them, when she comes back to the page in her browser, she doesn't know which report it is unless she looks at the URL (in case she didn't run it first, which happens).

Bottom line, I'd like to have the title of the report ABOVE the parameters, and haven't figured out how to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The parameter block is fixed on the page.

However, the URL shouldn't matter because the name of the report is in the folder view: I'd expect the title to match the name of the report...

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see any "folder view". Not sure what you refer to.

Comment: I don't have anything that looks like that.

Comment: @Amarundo: you *must* have a folder view of your reports. How do you deploy? Set permissions? View datasources?

Comment: see updated entry with new image. That's how it looks. And when a report is chosen, you can't see the name anymore, as in the first image I posted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: gbn, one more question: how do I change the font (they want larger font) of the name of the report? Please, see added image to original post. Thanks!

Comment: @Amarundo: that will be in the designer, which is visual studio etc.

Comment: gbn, where exactly? Note that I'm not talking about the actual report, but what appears on top of it, above the parameters. Thanks.

Comment: @Amarundo: you can't change this, unless you hack the CSS files. You'd have to Google/Bingle that to see if possible/already done

Answer (score 0):

The name of report is, with ssrs 2008 R2, displayed as the web page title. Even when the report has not been run and only parameters are visible. (In ssrs 2005, it was not displayed as the web page title. I do not know if it is a R2 specific feature.)
The web page title should be shown somewhere by the browser (it is browser dependent; a tabbed browser usually shows it on the tab header).
[image: example of ssrs 2008 R2 report viewed in a tabbed browser, title ListingReclamationOperation]
Unfortunately, it is indeed the report file name which is used as a title. It looks like there is no option for displaying a title other than the file name.

(A non-tabbed browser usually displays the web page title in its window label.)
[image: example of ssrs 2008 R2 report viewed in a non-tabbed browser, title ListingReclamationOperation]